# How do I integrate Okta and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, okta

I'm currently working on a web app project and trying to learn how to integrate Okta and MonngoDB, I was hoping to receive some guidance.

1. Is this even possible?
2. I'm unsure if this is even recommended, but to my understanding I can use Okta for secure authentication and authorization purposes, while MongoDB can be used to store corresponding data for a specific user that has been authenticated and authorized.

What I am having trouble understanding is, once a user is able to register for my web app their login data is being stored with Okta, so how do I go about attributing corresponding data for this user that would be stored in MongoDB? Would I use the Okta API to simultaneously GET the userID created during the registration process and store this in MongoDB? I've tried looking for tutorials and guides but have not had luck finding any.

More Info: I'm using the MERN stack for my web app and Google Cloud Platform.

Any guidance and help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: if you are using token.. you can get it after you login.. just extract the token Id or access token.  if it doesn't contain the userId then you can update the scope and add the userId claim.

Answer (score 0):

Our docs on managing federated authentication are here. It's a complex topic.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/manage-federated-auth/